# Problems while trying to load my assembly info file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly

I'm using the Visual Studio 2017 to build a Web site.
When I start my Project I've noticed that there was no any Assembly Information File.
Thus I couldn't load and retrieve the Attributes I need.
Therefore I've create a sub-folder Named `My Project` And I've put inside a file named `AssemblyInfo.vb` which it looks like that:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("ffffffff")>
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("ddddddddd")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("ccccccccccc")>
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("hhhhhhhhhhhhh")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © gggggggggg")>
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("vvvvvvvvvv")>

<Assembly: ComVisible(True)>

<Assembly: Guid("53a50112-05e2-43c2-b98c-d86d10b00048")>
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.27.3")>
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.27.3")>
<Assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")>
```

From that point I use my code behind in order to `get` the informations I need.
And in the line

```
Dim asm As Object = Nothing
asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(AsseFile)
```

"AsseFile" is the full path to the `AssemblyInfo.vb`
Throws me the error of:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///D:\WorkOnD\Work\Adata\Project\EKKEROSS\entry\entry\My
>   Project\AssemblyInfo.vb' or one of its dependencies. The module was
>   expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I'm using ".NET Framework 4.0.7".
My OS is windows 7 Ulimate
And I work in VS 2017
In dev Language vb.net

Is there someone to assist me? 
**NOTICE**
I look all the other solution answers but I didn't find any related solution to my issue
**ADDITION**
The code I use in order to read the file is:

```
Dim asm As Object = Nothing
            asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
            Dim FVI() As Object = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(True)
            For n As Integer = 0 To FVI.Count - 1
                If FVI(n).TypeId.Name = "AssemblyCopyrightAttribute" Then
                    CopyRight = FVI(n).Copyright
                End If
            Next<br/>
```

But there is no any Attribute name like that I want... 
I figure that I have an old version o Web site environment.

Comment: AsseFile must be the path to a DLL, not a .vb file.

Comment: @Hans Passant Yes dear you have an absolute right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AssemblyInfo.vb file is source code, it needs to be included in the project and compiled in to the final .dll Assembly

The function `Assembly.LoadFrom` (and its variants) will load a compiled dll Assembly and not source code. Re-point the variablie `AsseFile` to point to the compiled assembly and you will be much closer to your desired solution. Refer to: [Assembly.LoadFrom Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.7.2)

The path that you pass to `Assembly.LoadFrom` will depend on where the assembly is located on your file system, it will be something like:

```
AsseFile = "D:\WorkOnD\Work\Adata\Project\EKKEROSS\entry\entry\bin\debug\entry.dll"
```

And then you can do:

```
asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(AsseFile)
```

The file/folder structure for my test project is as below, you should map your project settings appropriately.

Project Name: **VBUnitTest**

The Project Directory is where the `.vbproj` file lives

Project Dir: **D:\Projects\Test Apps\VBUnitTests**

The Build output path is `bin\debug` by default, this can be confirmed/changed in the Project Settings dialog/window.

Build output path: **D:\Projects\Test Apps\VBUnitTests\bin\Debug**

For my test project, the variable `AsseFile` would hold the value: `D:\Projects\Test Apps\VBUnitTests\bin\Debug\VBUnitTest.dll`

Now, you wrote that you MANUALLY created the `My Project` folder and also the `AssemblyInfo.vb` file, did you add these new items to the project as well?

To confirm the `AssemblyInfo.vb` file is included in the project, click the `View All Files` option on the toolbar part of the Solution Explorer (icon with a blue square in my screenshot). You should see the `AssemblyInfo.vb` file listed as per the screenshot WITH a nice VB icon next to it. If there is no VB icon next to it and just a dotted document icon, then the file is not included in the project.

[image: Solution Explorer]

File included in the project

[image: Included in project][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRcoO.png)

File NOT included in project

[image: Not included in project]

To include the file in the project, right-click it and select the option `Include in Project`

[image: File right-click]

Comment: There is only one directory Bin and that is only in the root.
Contains only one subdirectory named `roslyn` and a file named `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`. Sorry but I'm confused, can you give few more details ?

Comment: @LefterisGkinis I have added some more information and edited to hopefully include all the information you need. Please review and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Good day... From what I've see the file is included in the project but it is not read it,
Please see in my post in order to look in my code trying to red this file.
Additionally I've see that I'm using a Previous Versions of Web site. therefore I was delete it and start a new web and all is fine.
But thanks anyhow